# Terraform nested list concatenation

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm working on a Terraform project where I need to create nested subdirectories in Azure Data Lake Gen2 based on a variable value. Given an input list like:

```
input_list = {
  "a" = {
    "a1" = {}
    "a2" = {}
  }
  "b" = {
    "b1" = {}
    "b2" = {
      "b21" = {}
    }
  }
}
```

I want to generate a new list that contains directory paths as follows:

`new_list = ["a/a1", "a/a2", "b/b1", "b/b2/b21"]`

I need help in implementing the logic to transform input_list into new_list. Here's what I have so far:

```
locals {
  paths = <Some Logic on var.directories which returns output similar to above new_list>
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "example" {
  for_each           = local.paths
  path               = each.key
  filesystem_name    = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.name
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  resource           = "directory"
}
```

I need help with the logic to generate new_list from input_list and use it to create the directories in Azure Data Lake Gen2. Any suggestions or thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution assuming that your structure is only 3 levels deep...

Functions I'm using here:

- `keys` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/keys
  Just to get the top keys of the current object
- `length` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/length
  This I use in a condition to see if we have keys
- `flatten` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten
  The final structure is a multi-dimensional array (not flat), we use this to get it flat.

```txt
variable "input_list" {
  default = {
    "a" = {
      "a1" = {}
      "a2" = {}
    }
    "b" = {
      "b1" = {}
      "b2" = {
        "b21" = {}
      }
    }
  }
}

locals {
  paths = flatten([
    for k0 in keys(var.input_list) : [
      for k1 in keys(var.input_list[k0]) : [
        length(keys(var.input_list[k0][k1])) > 0
        ? [for k2 in keys(var.input_list[k0][k1]) : "${k0}/${k1}/${k2}"]
        : ["${k0}/${k1}"]
      ]
    ]
  ])
}

output "paths" {
  value = local.paths
}
```

when we do a terraform plan on that we will get:

```txt
terraform plan

Changes to Outputs:
  + paths = [
      + "a/a1",
      + "a/a2",
      + "b/b1",
      + "b/b2/b21",
    ]
```

That should give you an idea what to do **IF** your structure has a max amount of levels, you can use this same technique to extract what you need, just add more nested loops to match your max.

If you do not know the amount of levels, you will need a recursive way to navigate the directory and I honestly don't think that is possible with the builtin functions from Terraform, you might need to extract that with some other tool/script then pass it as an input parameter.